# What causes git's post-receive umask to be different from the user's umask?

Tags: git, gitolite, umask

After some digging and help here [from other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38789261/how-to-find-out-what-causes-file-permissions-to-change-when-checking-out-files-w), I found out that I have a problem with the `umask` setting in git. What I want to achieve is that any git repo that is being checked out on my server, that the `umask` setting defaults to 0002. I don't want to have to configure this in every post-receive hook... I want this to be the default `umask`. How do I achieve that?

My repositories are uploaded by logging in to ssh with the `git` user on the server. When I check the `umask` setting, this is already set to the right setting:

```
root@server:~# su git 
git@server:~$ umask
0002
```

However, if I put `umask > /tmp/debug.log` in my post-receive hook, then that file shows an `umask` of 0077! What causes this to be different?

The root server also has the same `umask` and I just can't figure out why the `umask` is different when I check out a repository. If I change to the `git` user and create a file, then all works well:

```
git@server:~$ touch newfile
git@server:~$ ls -la
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 git git    0 Aug  6 02:17 newfile
-rw------- 1 git git    0 Aug  6 02:16 post
```

`newfile` is the file I just created, The `post` file is a file I checked out via git, clearly with different permissions. I also added `umask` to the .bashrc of the git user, but to no avail:

```
git@server:~$ cat ~/.bashrc 
export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
umask 0002
```

For what it's worth, I use gitolite to manage my repositories.

And this an example post-receive hook script I use:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/user/www/
git checkout -f
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to locate the startup scripts used by the shell when invoked from the post-receive hook, in non-interactive mode.

If your hook script starts with `#!/bin/sh`,
then look at `man sh` and look for mentions of rcfiles like `.profile`, `/etc/profile`, `.bashrc` or similar. The man page of the shell used should explain what files are sourced in case of interactive and non-interactive shells. You're looking for the files used in non-interactive mode.

If this is still not clear from the man page,
you can find what `/bin/sh` links to using `namei /bin/sh`, and run the command with `--help`.

To verify what you understood from the scripts used in the startup sequence,
you can add some debugging lines in the suspected script files, for example:

```
{ echo this is file x; umask; } >> /tmp/debug.log
```

And then get the post-receive hook triggered and look at `/tmp/debug.log`.

Comment: Hm, I see. Nice answer btw!

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out it *does* matter that I am using gitolite. Why? Because there is a setting in the gitolite configuration that dictates the umask of new files. Oddly I never had to change this setting in previous gitolite installs, but perhaps the default has been changed. In any way, here is how I finally sorted it out:

Open the `~/.gitolite.rc` file:

Locate this line:

```
$REPO_UMASK = 0077;
```

And change it to the setting of choice, eg:

```
$REPO_UMASK = 0002;
```

Things finally worked afterwards!