# What does git mean by “unable to migrate objects to permanent storage” with vscode

Tags: git, git-push

I build a bare repo in linux
when i use vscode in windows to write codes, and upload linux then git(version 2.17.0) push xxxx master, met this:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 321 bytes | 160.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unable to write sha1 filename 
./objects/ee/316617d17c8663636d107424531ba42f382f10: Permission denied
To /home/suny/test/git/project/arm
! [remote rejected] master -> master (unable to migrate objects to permanent 
storage)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/suny/test/git/project/arm'
```

i tested when i write code in linux and git push xxxx master, it`s no error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will get much more help if you can provide a step-by-step example that reproduces this error. Start with the original `git init` or `git clone` command and give all other commands that you performed to cause this error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does git mean by, "unable to migrate objects to permanent storage"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214667/what-does-git-mean-by-unable-to-migrate-objects-to-permanent-storage)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+unable+to+migrate+objects+to+permanent++storage

Answer (score 3):

You're running into a file system permission error.

This isn't a git problem. What user accounts are you using to upload and apply changes with?

If you're using multiple accounts, you'll need to make sure you've got Linux group permissions configured.

More reading material: https://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine

Comment: yes, i build a bare repo, my grouper and i use this, but i`m sure he is the same group to me.  so see the link first~

Comment: There's some config needed for git to play well with groups.