# Git Push Failure : unable to migrate objects to permanent storage

Tags: git, git-push, git-non-bare-repository

I have a local repository which I have cloned to another directory on the same machine.

When I do some changes on the clone and commit and then push
I get the following error message

I emphasize again that both the cloned repository from which i do the push
and the target repository are local and i have Read/Write access to both.

```
Rafael@MachineID MINGW64 /i/..path.. /Git Clones/Main_Model_Clone (master)
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 267, done.
Counting objects: 100% (267/267), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (146/146), done.
Writing objects: 100% (146/146), 52.46 KiB | 55.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 146 (delta 139), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (139/139), completed with 120 local objects.
error: unable to write file ./objects/pack/pack-299a7ef5ff8b23d37057bcedcfe27a1f0d45d540.idx: Permission denied
To file://i:/ .. path ..  /Main_Model
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unable to migrate objects to permanent storage)
error: failed to push some refs to 'file://i:/ .. path ..  /Main_Model'
```

Having encountered this post
[What does git mean by, "unable to migrate objects to permanent storage"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214667/what-does-git-mean-by-unable-to-migrate-objects-to-permanent-storage)

I understand i have a permission problem on the remote local repository
so i check the files on the local remote directory : .git/objects/pack
and indeed one file is readonly

```
Rafael@MachineID MINGW64 /i/.. path ..  /Main_Model/.git/objects/pack (GIT_DIR!)
$ ls -l
total 1580
-rw-r--r-- 1 udoai14 1049089    8520 מרץ  5 11:41 pack-299a7ef5ff8b23d37057bcedcfe27a1f0d45d540.idx
-r--r--r-- 1 udoai14 1049089 1604176 מרץ  5 13:19 pack-299a7ef5ff8b23d37057bcedcfe27a1f0d45d540.pack
```

but executing chmod -R g+w * on the objects folder  as suggested in the first answer comment doesn't help
because on the next push the file changes back from rw to r-

i also tried

git config core.sharedRepository true
like in this post

https://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine

but pushing again yields the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears i had a branch with two stashes 
in the local remote to which i tried to push.

Deleting the branch with git branch -d

and deleting the stashes with
git stash list and git stash drop

Solved the problem