# How to make git checkout files permission mode are 777?

Tags: git

I use `root` to run git,the files permission mode changed to `root 644` each time when I checkout, which means `apache` cannot delete,modify.
Then I decide to make GIT to checkout files with permission `777`. I know set umask 000(default is `022`) can do that, but I don't want to change my centos setting.
How to do it?

Comment: Setting files to mode 777 is almost never a good idea since it defeats *any* security. See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3242282/421705) for better (i.e. better integrated and more secure) ways to set the permissions. Also, have a look at the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#git-init---sharedfalsetrueumaskgroupallworldeverybody0xxx) for details and more options.

Comment: To mode 777 is for avoid any permission problem. It's my develop pc, not production server.

Comment: You're trying to use Git as a deployment tool. Git is a bad deployment tool. Instead, a proper install/deployment tool would handle building and installing and setting permissions. You'd do all of that as a normal user, only requiring you to use `sudo` to do the install. Its a bad habit to do anything root.

Answer (score 3):

With [Git 2.9 or more, you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285462/6309)

```
git add --chmod=+x -- afile
git commit -m "Executable!"
```

Then, on the next clone or checkout, the file will be executable.

Sidenote: a proper [`umask` would be 022 (for 755) or 002 for 775](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25441170/6309). 777 is generally not recommended.

Note 777 (even with `git update-index`) does not make sense, as [Git itself does not record write: only `644` or `755`, spelled `100644` and `100755`, with the `100` part meaning "regular file"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40979867/6309).

Comment: `777` is for my IDE to revise file content.

Answer (score 2):

`git config core.sharedRepository 0664`. See [git help config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

PS. I use mode 664 because it's more secure than wide-open 666. Git adds executable bit (thus making the mode 775 or 777) for directories automatically.

Comment: `664` means apache cannot delete file in this folder. Based on VonC answer, `666` is not allowed in git.

Comment: Then `chown -R apache.apache` (or www-data.www.data) and always do `su - apache` to work with that repo. That way you guarantee Apache will always has r/w access.

Answer (score 1):

`find . -type f -not -name '.git*' | xargs chmod 777

find . -type d -not -name '.git*' | xargs chmod 666`
I use this in post-checkout hooks and seemed without any problem till now.